# Koin viewModel implement parent viewmodel interface

Tags: android, koin

I'm declaring my viewmodel like this:

`viewModel(qualifier = named<CustomersViewModel>()) { (savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) -> CustomersViewModel(savedStateHandle) }`

and In the activity like this:

`private val customersViewModel by stateViewModel<CustomersViewModel>(qualifier = named<CustomersViewModel>())`

No problem with that. I can use the ViewModel with no problem.

I then have another viewModel that if I do:

`private val anotherViewModel by sharedViewModel<CustomersViewModel>()`

I can access the shared ViewModel and call methods in the `CustomersViewModel`.

The problem with this approach is that `anotherViewModel` now has access to all the methods in `CustomersViewModel`.

I've created an interface, that `CustomersViewModel` implements that only exposes the methods needed for `anotherViewModel`.

I've then replaced the `sharedViewModel` by `viewModel` and tried using:

`viewModel { AnotherViewModel(get(), get(qualifier = named<CustomersViewModel>() as CustomersInterface), get()) }`
but I'm always getting `NoBeanDefFoundException`

Is it possible to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Create a viewmodel that has the methods you only want for anotherViewModel and declare it as open. Then let customersViewModel inherit from that model and add your other methods that the anotherViewModel is not allowed to see.